# Long operation on startup WPF app

Tags: wpf, mvvm, backgroundworker

I want some data to be loaded from DB on application startup.

What I want is to show main window first, with progress bar, and status text like "data is loading" while operation run.

How should I do this actually?

I'm initilizing my DB connection (`DbConn`) and `MainWindow` itself from `Application_Startup`:

```
protected void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            DbConn= new DBConnection();
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = DbConn.GetLocalCulture();
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
            main = new MainWindow();
            main.Show();
        }
```

I have background worker on `MainWindow`, and initializing my window model there:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = new Models.MyModel(App.DbConn);
            InitializeComponent();
            BgWLoad = new BackgroundWorker();
            BgWLoad.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
            BgWLoad.DoWork += BgwLoad_DoWork;
            BgWLoad.ProgressChanged += BgwLoad_ProgressChanged;
            BgWLoad.RunWorkerCompleted += BgwLoad_RunWorkerCompleted;
}
```

Where I should run my worker (`BgWLoad.RunWorkerAsync`)?

The logic of lading data from DB is currently placed on MyModel side, and progress is reported as callback:

```
private void BgwLoadQK_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            StatusText.Text = Properties.Resources.msgLoadingKeySets;
            Model.Init((double progress) =>
            {
                ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32(progress));
            });
        }
```

Is this OK to do so?

Or how on Earth this should be organized using best practice?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the MainWindow shown before kicking off processes, I use the MainWindow.ContentRendered event to start the process which is fired when the view is layed out and shown.